# Assembler code compilation throws linker error

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, compilation, x86

I have a challenge I am trying to do and I want to translate some assembler code into c code. What I am currently attempting to do is compile the assembler code into an executable and then decompile it into c code(if you know a simpler way please alert me)

However, when compiling the code using `nasm -f elf main.asm` and `gcc -o main main.o` (I have also used `gcc -m32 -o main main.o` to no avail)

The first command runs with no errors, whilst the latter fails returning:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
```

I am aware that the assembler code isn't perfect, my goal isn't to be able to run the program but simply to see what it is like as C code.

```
section .text
  global _main
_main:
  jmp 0x40
  pop eax
  mov ecx, eax
  mov ebx, 0x0
  mov edx, 0x53
  xor eax, eax
  mov al,BYTE [ecx+ebx*1]
  or cl,BYTE [edx]
  push ebx
  push ecx
  push eax
  mov ecx, esp
  mov eax, 0x4
  mov ebx, 0x1
  push edx
  mov edx, 0xa000001
  or al,BYTE [eax]
  int 0x80
  pop edx
  pop ecx
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  inc ebx
  inc ebx
  dec edx
  jne 0x13
  mov eax,0x1
  mov ebx,0xa0a0000
  add BYTE [eax],al
  int 0x80
  call 0x8
```

I have tried removing the underscore, and using `_start` instead.
What can I do to make this code compile?

Comment: This is for Linux?  It should be `global main` and  `main:`, and yes you need to link with `gcc -m32` because you define a main, not a _start.  Also, `jmp 0x40` is going to make your code crash right away.

Comment: I assume given the message in the question you are on MacOS?

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?  If you are on macos, elf is the wrong object type.  Use `macho32`  and then fix the section name which should be `text`  iirc.

Comment: @fuz I have tried using macho32 but the error is the same. Also using `text` instead of `.text` makes `nasm -f macho32 main.asm` fail.

Comment: @Chronos Sorry, the section name should indeed be `__text` or `.text`.  I remembered this incorrectly.  I still have no idea what the problem is.  It's hard to test for me since I don't have a computer with macOS available.